# Inserting dataframe from Python into Snowflake

Tags: python, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I try to insert dataframe into a table in snowflake using the writes_pandas function, only null values ​​appear in the table. I was trying to create a table that does not contain null values, but when I made code that inserts dataframe into Snowflake, it reported an error that NULL values ​​cannot be inserted into a table that stores NOT NULL values. Can someone maybe help me solve the problem? I checked, the dataframe in Python is not null.

```
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd
import snowflake.connector
import glob
from snowflake.connector.pandas_tools import write_pandas

ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
   user='****',
   password='****',
   account='****'

)
cs= ctx.cursor()

def split(filehandler, keep_headers=True):
    reader = csv.reader(filehandler, delimiter=',')

    """
        Function split the file on row # basics
    """

    # Variable declartion:
    row_limit = 1000
    output_name_template = 'output_%s.csv'
    output_path = r'C:\Users\Nenad\Desktop\Data\mix'

    current_piece = 1
    current_out_path = os.path.join(
        output_path,
        output_name_template % current_piece
    )
    current_out_writer = csv.writer(open(current_out_path, 'w'), delimiter=',')
    current_limit = row_limit
    if keep_headers:
        headers = next(reader)
        current_out_writer.writerow(headers)
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        if i + 1 > current_limit:
            current_piece += 1
            current_limit = row_limit * current_piece
            current_out_path = os.path.join(
                output_path,
                output_name_template % current_piece
            )
            current_out_writer = csv.writer(open(current_out_path, 'w'), delimiter=',')
            if keep_headers:
                current_out_writer.writerow(headers)
        current_out_writer.writerow(row)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("file split Begins")
    split(open(r"C:\Users\Nenad\PycharmProjects\untitled15\bigtable_py.csv"))
    print("File split Ends")


os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Nenad\Desktop\Data\mix')
file_extension=".csv"
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob(f"*{file_extension}")]
sql = "USE role ACCOUNTADMIN" 
cs.execute(sql)
sql = "SELECT CURRENT_ROLE()"
cs.execute(sql)

for file in all_filenames:
 df=pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=',')
 cs.execute("USE DRAGANA")
 write_pandas(ctx, df, 'TABLES')
```

Comment: Can you share your code or snippet

Comment: I changed the post, now you can see the code

Comment: how big is your bigtable_py.csv? Try to create a sample file from it with 100 rows or so, read this file only and print your df after `df=pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=',')` line to see what's being written to Snowflake

Comment: Bigtable_py.csv has 69000 rows.

Comment: I tried with another smaller file, and it reports the same error

Comment: Did you look at the data frame contents before calling write_pandas? If the data is not structured properly, you might get null values easily

Comment: as per my understanding cs.execute will not fire unless  we have  cs.fetchone()

Comment: I solved the problem! Snowflake converts lowercase letters to uppercase, so the column names in the table and dataframe did not match.

Answer (score 0):

`write_pandas()` seems to have issues interpreting the dtypes of fields in DataFrame. SQLalchemy performs a much better job. I suggest using a snowflake sqlalchemy and get a sqlalchemy engine.
Using
`DataFame.to_sql()` solved most issues I personaaly had.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29944891)